# Castle Windsor PerWebRequest LifeStyle and Application_EndRequest

Tags: asp.net, castle-windsor, global-asax, perwebrequest

I'm registering some components related to Linq2Sql using PerWebRequest lifestyle.  I see them get created, but they get destroyed before my global's Application_EndRequest method gets called.  Is that by design?  Does anyone know a work around?  I want to call commit on my UnitOfWork object to submitchanges() at the end of every request.  In addition to using the Global.asax Application_EndResult, I've also tried an IHttpModule with the same results.

I'm using Castle 2.0.

Here's how I'm registering my stuff with PerWebRequest.  I am creating a DataCOntextProvider object that holds onto a L2S DataContext.  That object is injected into the UoW.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Register the IUnitOfWorkManager to resolve to LinqToSqlUnitOfWorkManager per web request
        /// </summary>
        public void RegisterLinq2SqlUnitOfWorkPerWebRequest()
        {
            _container.Register(Component.For<IUnitOfWorkManager>()
              .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
              .ImplementedBy<LinqToSqlUnitOfWorkManager>());
        }

    /// <summary>
    /// Register the IDataContextProvider to resolve to DataContextProvider per web request
    /// </summary>
    public void RegisterDataContextProviderPerWebRequest()
    {
        _container.Register(Component.For<IDataContextProvider>()
          .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
          .ImplementedBy<DataContextProvider>());
    }
```

Now I am simply trying to pull the UoW from the container via the CommonServiceLocator (both CSL and Windsor Adapter are 1.0) from the EndRequest like this:

```
 protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ignore unless this is a page (.aspx) or handler (.ashx)
        if (!RequestCanHaveContext())
            return;

        //get the IUnitOfWork manager
        var uow = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUnitOfWorkManager>();

        //if we have one, commit changes at the end of the request
        if (uow != null)
        {
            //don't explicitly dispose of uow or we'll get Disposed exceptions on the context
            uow.Commit();
        }

    }
```

Thanks,
Corey

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/b8f52a3640ffb654

Comment: did you verify that the endrequest handler of your module runs before component destruction? Also, where/how are you handling the kernel's destroyed event?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your `Application_EndRequest` code to a httpmodule and 
register it before the `PerWebRequestLifestyleModule`.

Comment: I did do that.  I am ending up with very wierd behavior - things getting created/destroyed without firing the Micro Kernel's Destroyed event.  I don't know if it ASP.NET that is causing me pain.

Comment: did you verify that the endrequest handler of your module runs before component destruction? Also, where/how are you handling the kernel's destroyed event?

Answer (score 1):

your implementation of `IUnitOfWorkManager` should implement `IDisposable` and in Dispose call SubmitChanges. Alternatively use custom decommission submit changes concern.